# Remove base class name from Jackson serialization with JsonTypeInfo

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jackson

Here is the inheritance setup I have :

abstract class `Animal`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include =JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class)})

public abstract class Animal {
}
```

concrete class Dog:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

  private final String breed;

  public Dog(String breed) {
      this.breed = breed;
  }

  public String getBreed() {
      return breed;
  }
}
```

A simple wrapper class for Animal:

```
public class AnimalWrapper {

  private final Animal animal;

  public AnimalWrapper(Animal animal) {
      this.animal = animal;
  }

  public Animal getAnimal() {
      return animal;
  }
}
```

Code for serialization:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Animal myDog = new Dog("english shepherd");
AnimalWrapper animalWrapper = new AnimalWrapper(myDog);
String dogJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(animalWrapper);
```

The value of `dogJson` is:

`{"animal":{"Dog":{"breed":"english shepherd"}}}`

**What I want** is a JSON without the base class name (animal):

`{"Dog":{"breed":"english shepherd"}}`

I have tried using `@JsonUnwrapped` around `animal` in `AnimalWrapper` in which case both `animal` and `Dog` are eliminated (which is not what I want):

`{"breed":"english shepherd"}`

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom `JsonSerializer` for your `AnimalWrapper` in order to skip that bit.

```
public class ResponseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<AnimalWrapper> {


    @Override
    public void serialize(AnimalWrapper value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        final Object animal = value.getAnimal();
        Class<?> responseClass = animal.getClass();
        JavaType responseJavaType = serializers.constructType(responseClass);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeFieldName(serializers.findTypeSerializer(responseJavaType).getTypeIdResolver().idFromValue(animal));
        serializers.findValueSerializer(responseClass).serialize(animal, gen, serializers);
        /* Here you must manually serialize other properties */
        /* Like gen.writeStringField("property", value.getProperty()); */
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Annotate your `AnimalWrapper` with a `@JsonSerialize` annotation and specify the custom serializer.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ResponseSerializer.class)
public class AnimalWrapper<T> {

  private final T animal;

  public AnimalWrapper(T animal) {
      this.animal = animal;
  }

  public T getAnimal() {
      return animal;
  }
}
```

A quick test:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Animal myDog = new Dog("english shepherd");
AnimalWrapper animalWrapper = new AnimalWrapper(myDog);
String dogJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(animalWrapper);
System.out.println(dogJson);
```

Output:

> {"dog":{"breed":"english shepherd"}}

Answer (score 0):

I think you have encountered one of the weaknesses of Jackson as detailed here...

[Unwrapped annotation issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/231)

The solution I would suggest is a custom serializer as described here...

[Jackson Custom Serializer](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/01/custom-serializer-jackson/)